# How to upgrade TeXLive 2009 to TeXLive 2010

Tags: installing, texlive

I have a TeXLive 2009 installation on my Linux machine. And, I'd like to upgrade it to TeXLive 2010. I tried the command `sudo tlmgr update --self --all` as suggested in [How to keep my TeX Live installation up to date?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/999/how-to-keep-my-tex-live-installation-up-to-date). But, I get the following error message.

> tlmgr: package repository http://.../mirrors/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
>
> The release version of the installation source and the installation media do not agree: source: 2010, media: 2009
>
> Please fix your location http://.../mirrors/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet at /usr/local/bin/tlmgr line 4205.

This error message makes me wonder if it's possible at all to upgrade from TeXLive 2009 to 2010 automatically by pointing my repository location to the right address.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Upgrading from 2009 to 2010 is not possible. The [bugs and updates](http://tug.org/texlive/bugs.html) page says the following:

> It is not possible to upgrade from TL 2009 to TL 2010, so install the new release in a new directory (as is done by default). install-tl may offer to import options (not packages) from a previous release, but results are not guaranteed.

Comment: This is also true for TL 2010 to TL 2011 and should be for TL in general.

Answer (score 9):

To save someone else the trouble of figuring out how to “upgrade” to a newer version of TeXLive, here are the details.

1. As [Taco Hoekwater](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3311/how-to-upgrade-texlive-2009-to-texlive-2010/3313#3313) said, install the new version. This will live in a different directory so it doesn't conflict with the older installation.
2. To uninstall the older version and reclaim disk space simply delete the folder from the old installation, e.g. `/usr/local/texlive/2009`.

   On OS X you can open a Finder window, choose “Go -> Go to Folder ...” from the menu and enter `/usr/local/texlive`. Then drag and drop the folder from the older version to the trash. You'll be prompted to type your password because the the folder is owned by root.

Comment: And don’t forget to update $PATH.

Comment: Right! I was doing this by installing MacTeX which (apparently) sets up the path as appropriate when installing the new version.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ArchLinux, the update should be as soon as your mirror gets an update! The best thing to do is:

**# pacman -Sy texlive-most**

that will install the hole texlive distribution!