# What's a simple way to migrate a TeXWorks (Windows) configuration from TexLive 2010 to 2011?

Tags: texlive, windows, texworks, updating

Following advice from the question [How to upgrade TeXLive 2009 to TeXLive 2010](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3311/how-to-upgrade-texlive-2009-to-texlive-2010), I'm installing TeXLive 2011 (on Windows Vista) in a new directory. Overall, this seems fine, after copying my texmf-local tree and running `mktexlsr`, but all of my TeXWorks settings are reset to the default.

This includes both editor options (like editor font settings) and typesetting options (e.g. I added a menu item for glossary processing with `makeindex`)

Is there an easy but safe way of:

1. Finding where they are?; and
2. Merging them?; or
3. Safely copying my (old) settings over the new ones?
4. Altering my Windows file associations at the moment I'm ready for the definitive move from 2010 to 2011?

Comment: the config is saved under  `~/.TeXworks` and it will be overwritten with a new installation. You have to save it before an update.

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that I'm on Windows. I've updated the question...

Comment: then it is saved in your User part under the directory `.texliveYYYY`, there is a dot in front!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Herbert said, there's a `.texliveYYYY` folder in your home directory.

So for question 1 (where are the TeXworks files?), in my relatively untouched install, there's a `.texliveYYY\texmf-config\texworks` folder with the following:

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is B068-2864

 Directory of C:\Users\me\.texlive2010\texmf-config\texworks

07/08/2011  11:10 AM              .
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              ..
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              completion
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              configuration
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              dictionaries
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              scripts
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              translations
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              TUG
07/22/2011  06:12 PM             1,277 TwFileVersions.db
               1 File(s)          1,277 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\me\.texlive2010\texmf-config\texworks\completion

07/08/2011  11:10 AM              .
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              ..
07/08/2011  11:10 AM             1,165 tw-basic.txt
07/08/2011  11:10 AM             1,903 tw-beamer.txt
07/08/2011  11:10 AM                53 tw-context.txt
07/08/2011  11:10 AM            20,182 tw-latex.txt
               4 File(s)         23,303 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\me\.texlive2010\texmf-config\texworks\configuration

07/08/2011  11:10 AM              .
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              ..
07/08/2011  11:10 AM               803 auto-indent-patterns.txt
07/08/2011  11:10 AM               215 delimiter-pairs.txt
07/08/2011  11:10 AM               377 smart-quotes-modes.txt
07/08/2011  11:10 AM             1,704 syntax-patterns.txt
07/08/2011  11:10 AM             1,208 tag-patterns.txt
07/08/2011  11:10 AM             1,590 texworks-config.txt
               6 File(s)          5,897 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\me\.texlive2010\texmf-config\texworks\dictionaries

07/08/2011  11:10 AM              .
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\me\.texlive2010\texmf-config\texworks\scripts

07/08/2011  11:10 AM              .
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              ..
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              Hooks
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              LaTeX styles
07/08/2011  11:10 AM               278 launchPdf.js
07/08/2011  11:10 AM               392 makeBold.lua
07/08/2011  11:10 AM               379 makeBold.py
07/08/2011  11:10 AM               476 system.js
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              Text transforms
               4 File(s)          1,525 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\me\.texlive2010\texmf-config\texworks\scripts\Hooks

07/08/2011  11:10 AM              .
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              ..
07/08/2011  11:10 AM             1,795 babelLanguage.js
07/08/2011  11:10 AM             4,446 latexErrors.js
               2 File(s)          6,241 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\me\.texlive2010\texmf-config\texworks\scripts\LaTeX styles

07/08/2011  11:10 AM              .
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              ..
07/08/2011  11:10 AM               825 toggleBold.js
07/08/2011  11:10 AM               827 toggleEmph.js
               2 File(s)          1,652 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\me\.texlive2010\texmf-config\texworks\scripts\Text transforms

07/08/2011  11:10 AM              .
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              ..
07/08/2011  11:10 AM             2,527 titlecase.js
               1 File(s)          2,527 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\me\.texlive2010\texmf-config\texworks\translations

07/08/2011  11:10 AM              .
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\me\.texlive2010\texmf-config\texworks\TUG

07/08/2011  11:10 AM              .
07/08/2011  11:10 AM              ..
07/22/2011  06:12 PM            10,030 TeXworks.ini
               1 File(s)         10,030 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
              21 File(s)         52,452 bytes
              29 Dir(s)  376,468,918,272 bytes free
```

For questions 2-3 (how to merge or use all of the old settings?), I'd backup the settings from both the older version and 2011, and then check them for differences, or possibly just overwrite the new files with the old contents. An editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) can make the file comparison simpler, if you don't already have better tools for that.

For question 4 (how to set file associations?), I think TeX Live Manager will handle that. Start the new version's tlmgr, and go to "Options / General". There's a "Change file associations" entry there that can be set to none, new, or all.

[image]