# Can't use pstricks - boundingbox error

Tags: pdftex, pstricks

This is a technical problem arising from this question: [Bending snakes with xy-pic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31687/bending-snakes-with-xy-pic/31694#31694) and also regarding the accepted answer to this question: 
[How to use PSTricks in pdfLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/how-to-use-pstricks-in-pdflatex)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=1.75cm,yunit=1cm,nodesep=3pt}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(5,6)
%\psgrid    % useful during construction
% put the nodes in- working from the bottom upwards
% bottom row
\psnode(1,0){10}{$0$}
\psnode(2,0){20}{$0$}
\psnode(3,0){30}{$0$}
% second row
\psnode(1,1){cokerl}{coker $\lambda$}
\psnode(2,1){cokerm}{coker $\mu$}
\psnode(3,1){cokern}{coker $\nu$}
% third row
\psnode(0,2){02}{$0$}
\psnode(1,2){L0}{$L_0$}
\psnode(2,2){M0}{$M_0$}
\psnode(3,2){N0}{$N_0$}
\psnode(4,2){42}{$0$}
% fourth row
\psnode(0,3){03}{$0$}
\psnode(1,3){L1}{$L_1$}
\psnode(2,3){M1}{$M_1$}
\psnode(3,3){N1}{$N_1$}
\psnode(4,3){43}{$0$}
% fifth row
\psnode(0,4){04}{$0$}
\psnode(1,4){kerl}{ker $\lambda$}
\psnode(2,4){kerm}{ker $\mu$}
\psnode(3,4){kern}{ker $\nu$}
% sixth row
\psnode(1,5){15}{$0$}
\psnode(2,5){25}{$0$}
\psnode(3,5){35}{$0$}
% horizontal arrows
% 2nd row
\ncline{->}{cokerl}{cokerm}
\ncline{->}{cokerm}{cokern}
% 3rd row
\ncline{->}{02}{L0}
\ncline{->}{L0}{M0}
\nbput{$\alpha_0$}
\ncline{->}{M0}{N0}
\nbput{$\beta_0$}
\ncline{->}{N0}{42}
% 4th row
\ncline{->}{03}{L1}
\ncline{->}{L1}{M1}
\naput{$\alpha_1$}
\ncline{->}{M1}{N1}
\naput{$\beta_1$}
\ncline{->}{N1}{43}
% 5th row
\ncline{->}{04}{kerl}
\ncline{->}{kerl}{kerm}
\ncline{->}{kerm}{kern}
% vertical arrows
\ncline{->}{cokerl}{10}
\ncline{->}{cokerm}{20}
\ncline{->}{cokern}{30}
\ncline{->}{L0}{cokerl}
\ncline{->}{M0}{cokerm}
\ncline{->}{N0}{cokern}
\ncline{->}{L1}{L0}
\nbput{$\lambda$}
\ncline{->}{M1}{M0}
\nbput{$\mu$}
\ncline{->}{N1}{N0}
\nbput{$\nu$}
\ncline{->}{kerl}{L1}
\ncline{->}{kerm}{M1}
\ncline{->}{kern}{N1}
\ncline{->}{15}{kerl}
\ncline{->}{25}{kerm}
\ncline{->}{35}{kern}
\nccurve[angleA=0,angleB=180]{->}{kern}{cokerl}
% npos takes a value between 0 and 1 for \nccurve
\naput[npos=0.1]{$\delta$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

I'm running linux. When compiling with the command `pdflatex -shell-escape FILE` I get the following:

```
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)

! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in a1p7-2011.snake-pics.pdf (no
 BoundingBox).
```

Here's my file list:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pstricks.sty    2011/04/23 v0.50 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
pstricks.tex    2011/04/23 v2.20 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 xkeyval.sty    2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
  pst-fp.tex    2011/04/23 v2.20 `PST-fp' (hv)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pst-node.sty    2010/04/22 package wrapper for pst-node.tex
pst-node.tex    2011/05/05 1.16 `pst-node' (tvz)
auto-pst-pdf.sty    2009/04/26 v0.6 Wrapper for pst-pdf
ifplatform.sty    2010/10/22 v0.4 Testing for the operating system
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/04/22 v0.16 Utilities of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
catchfile.sty    2011/03/01 v1.6 Catches the contents of a file (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
       a.w18
 pst-pdf.sty    2008/10/09 v1.1v PS graphics for pdfLaTeX (RN,HjG)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
 preview.sty    2010/02/14 11.86 (AUCTeX/preview-latex)
   dvips.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
 environ.sty    2008/06/18 v0.2 A new way to define environments
supp-pdf.mkii
  a-pics.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you have a period in your filename. Try changing it to `a1p72011snakepics.tex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to recreate your problem using the filename that I got from your error code:

```
 a1p7-2011.snake-pics.tex
```

I think the problem is that you have a period (full stop) in your filename. Try changing it to

```
a1p72011snakepics.tex
```

Following the comment, make sure that your packages are up to date. Add the `\listfiles` immediately before your `\begin{document}` and compare it to the following output. If it is different, then the first step is to update your distribution.

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pstricks.sty    2011/08/201 v0.51 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
pstricks.tex    2011/09/04 v2.23 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 xkeyval.sty    2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
  pst-fp.tex    2011/09/04 v2.23 `PST-fp' (hv)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pst-node.sty    2010/04/22 package wrapper for pst-node.tex
pst-node.tex    2011/08/20 1.20 `pst-node' (tvz)
auto-pst-pdf.sty    2009/04/26 v0.6 Wrapper for pst-pdf
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
ifplatform.sty    2010/10/22 v0.4 Testing for the operating system
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/04/22 v0.16 Utilities of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
catchfile.sty    2011/03/01 v1.6 Catches the contents of a file (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
  myfile.w18
 pst-pdf.sty    2008/10/09 v1.1v PS graphics for pdfLaTeX (RN,HjG)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
 preview.sty    2010/02/14 11.86 (AUCTeX/preview-latex)
   dvips.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
 environ.sty    2008/06/18 v0.2 A new way to define environments
supp-pdf.mkii
myfile-pics.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
```

**EDIT**: `\usepackage[multidot]{grffile}` is a much simpler solution which doesn't require renaming the file.

Comment: Yes, that's it. How odd. Now it compiles, but I'm not getting what I should be getting. I'm getting a pdf with "(1,0)100 (2,0)200 (3,0)300 (1,1)cokerlcoker λ (2,1)cokermcoker μ (3,1)cokerncoker ν (0,2)020 (1,2)L0L0 (2,..."

Comment: @BrunoStonek See my update- add `\listfiles` and compare to my output

Comment: Oh, indeed, there are some packages slightly out of date, see my OP for the list. Again, how odd. I'm runing the latext texlive, shouldn't it just work? Manually updating the packages is quite a chore...

Comment: @BrunoStonek See this link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/999/how-to-keep-my-tex-live-installation-up-to-date and

Comment: Your second link didn't appear. I thank you most sincerely for all of your help, this is probably the reason why it's not working. Alas, I can't use "tlmgr" (tex live manager) since I use arch linux and the package is out of date and doesn't work with texlive 2011. I could spend a couple more hours trying to make it work, but I'm tired already of messing around with these things, and the effort is not worth the reward :P I guess I'll retry when TexLive 2012 comes around ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the filename is really the culprit, a `\usepackage[multidot]{grffile}` should help. There's no need to rename the file.