# Do I need to run non-tlmgr tools each time I use Tex Live Utility to update Tex?

Tags: installing, texlive, mactex, updating

I've made some modifications to my TeX installation outside of the TeX Live Utility, which I use primarily, as a convenient way to keep my installation up to date. For example, I've added some fonts manually followed by `texhash`, and some others [using `getnonfreefonts`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47504/7844).

Does that mean that after each time I run TeXLive Utility (or [tlmgr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1002/7844)), I need to rerun any and all other config tools I might have used outside of TeX Live (e.g., `texhash` or `udmap`)?

Comment: No. Why should it be necessary?

Comment: @egreg: A comment on a [another post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47504/7844) made me wonder, and I'm not familiar enough with the tools to know how they interact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install fonts in the "local" tree (`/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`) then you'll run `updmap-sys` for making them known to the system and no intervention should be necessary in case `tlmgr` updates font related packages.

The `getnonfreefonts-sys` tool just does this automatically.

The situation would be very different if you installed fonts in your personal tree (`~/texmf` on GNU/Linux systems or `~/Library/texmf` on Mac OS X) and made them known with `updmap` (or you used `getnonfreefonts`).

In this case changes made to the system wide font map would *not* be reflected in the personal font map that `updmap` has created. Therefore it's always best to do "global" font installations and `updmap` should be run each time an update to TeX Live acts on font related packages.

Comment: Likewise for fonts I add manually followed by `texhash` I assume, as long as I put them in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius `mktexlsr` (the real name of `texhash` is automatically performed by `tlmgr` after any update and it acts also on the local tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed your fonts in TEXMFHOME, check the box for "Automatically enable fonts in my home directory" in TeX Live Utility's preferences, and it will run updmap for you after an update/install.

Comment: Very useful feature, although I think it's better to install fonts in `$TEXMFLOCAL`.

Comment: Well, I think it's better not to install fonts in either location, and just use XeTeX :). There are good arguments on either side, but this was something that several long-time users found helpful.

Comment: By the way, welcome to TeX.SX!